# Coefficient of characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a n$\times$n matrix $A$, let $f_i$ denotes the coefficient of $t^{n-i}$ term of the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Then if I regard every entries of $A$ as variables, $f_i$ is now a function.

Then when the Jacobian of $f_1,...,f_n$ is of full rank? Especially, when $A$ is nilpotent(i.e. all eigenvalues are 0) and with one jordan block, is the Jacobian of full rank?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Louis_L49930._Pennisi.pdf

Comment: @Hamza: In the case $n=2$, for the matrix $A = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ I get $J(A) = \left(\begin{matrix}-1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\0 & 0 & -1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$.

Comment: I don't understand the calculation very well can you explicite them or  send it to me ? @FriedrichPhilipp

Comment: Here's another article with a formula for the coefficients: http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0893965905002612/1-s2.0-S0893965905002612-main.pdf?_tid=139ff6aa-daa8-11e5-bc7e-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1456285292_376c8e602ba263c6f315af8c1be1a7a1

Comment: @Hamza: We have $\chi_A(t) = t^2 - (a + d)t + (ad-bc)$. Hence $f_0(A) = 1$, $f_1(A) = -(a+d)$ and $f_2(A) = ad-bc$. Let us neglect $f_0$ since its derivative is zero anyway (whatever $A$ is). Now, $f_1'(A) = (-1,0,0,-1)$ and $f_2'(A) = (d,-c,-b,a)$. This leads to the Jacobian of $F = (f_1,f_2)$ for the nilpotent matrix above.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Actually I believe this is true for all n, I am considering what about the similar matrix of the jordan form.

Comment: @Hamza We do derivation first, then plug into values. Therefore the jacobian might be not zero.